# Force Visual Studio to rebuild dependent projects

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

How can I force Visual Studio 2012 to rebuild all dependent projects when a project changes?

I have two projects: a C++ DLL, and a C# WPF app. The C# project has a post-build command to copy the DLL into the Debug folder.

When I modify the C++ project, the DLL is rebuilt, but the C# project isn't, and so the DLL isn't updated in the Debug folder. Then I need to clean and rebuild the solution before I see the updated results.

I'd like to tell VS that whenever I update the C++ project, it should rebuild the C# project (or at least run the post-build command). The C# project is dependent on the C++ project, but not through a reference.

Comment: have you tried simply setting a project dependency?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, those are all set up.

Comment: ugly, but perhaps add a post-build to the C++ project that `touch`-es a file in the C# project. if you don't have a `touch` tool on machine then there is one in `nmake` (poor man's `touch`).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Problem is, the C++ project is independent of the C# project. The C# project is one of many apps that could use the DLL.

Comment: don't know if symbolic link works for DLL, but perhaps you could use that instead of copy (hardlink runs risk of being invalidated by update of target)

Comment: If adding the C++ project as a dependency (under Project Dependencies...) does work, have you tried add the CPP project as *referenced* by the C# project instead? I just did this and it seems to work without a hitch.

Comment: @WhozCraig I can't reference an native project from a .NET project.

Comment: You can't? I just *did*. Or is this a restriction of your environment?

Comment: @WhozCraig Visual Studio says: "A reference to 'foobar' could not be added."

Comment: Odd. No issues with that at all here. Just to be sure I just modified the source in my CPP project, and built the solution. As expected, CPP built first, then C#.

Comment: @WhozCraig Is it a Win32 project? Or does it have some .NET code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17302/discussion-between-whozcraig-and-kendall-frey)

Comment: Excellent question. I have the exact problem right now, where a C# project is (semantically) dependent on a C++, Win32 project. It cannot "reference" it since it is an .exe file which gets copied in a post-build action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If setting the project dependency inside your solution does not help just try to include the .dll from the C++ project as a link into the other project, then it should recognize that the file was changed and should rebuild the project.

Comment: "include the .dll from the C++ project as a link into the other project" What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @KendallFrey I think it means add the dll as a "solution item" to the C# project.

Comment: @phoog That makes even less sense.

Comment: The big problem with this is that it relies on a specific configuration and/or platform, like Debug/x86, or Release/x64. That's not really optimal. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: One (absurd) way is to add all four combinations (Debug/x86, Debug/x64, Release/x86 and Release/x64). I will do this now but it really, REALLY feels crazy. :)

Comment: You can edit the project file manually in a text editor and modify the link to use the $(Configuration) and $(Platform) variables so that only one link is required

Comment: @Lummo Specifying `$(Configuration)` doesn't work for me. VS (2015 Update 3) always seems to resolve the property to `Debug` in this case, as I can see in the Properties window in the Full Path property.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on Peter's answer, this is what I did.

Right click on the C# project in the Solution Explorer, and select Add > Existing Item.

Browse to the C++ output folder, select the DLL file, and instead of opening it with the Add button, click the dropdown button beside it, and select Add As Link.

What I initially did next was right click on the link that was added to your C# project, and select Properties, then change Copy to Output Directory to Copy if newer. But then I realized that will copy the Debug version (since that's where the link was pointing to), instead of the current configuration. So I left it at Do not copy, since my command line automatically selects the right configuration.

So now the C# project has a link to the C++ project output, which will trigger a rebuild whenever the C++ project changes, even though the link has nothing to do with the output of the project.

For the record, here's my post-build command line in the C# project (foobar is the C++ DLL).

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration)\foobar.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Comment: This works, but if you add the link to the Debug version, it will only run when the Debug configuration is active. To make it work for Debug and Release, you need to add links for both.

Comment: How can I make this force the C++ dll to build as well?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following code into each dependent project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\Build\_buildforcer">
        <Visible>true</Visible>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="ForceNextBuild"
        AfterTargets="PrepareForRun"
        Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' ">

    <Touch Files="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\Build\_buildforcer"
           AlwaysCreate="true"/>
</Target>
```

You can do this by means of an `Import` if you want.
This forces the project to always build, not just when a project it depends on changes.

But hey, those dependent projects are often application projects, which are typically thin wrappers above business libraries. Moreover, a compilation isn't forced this way. It's just `MSBuild` executing all targets only to find out that everything is up to date. So, your `F5` performance won't be substantially degraded.

I've explicitly marked the `None` item as `Visible`, since the item must be visible for this mechanism to work. On a related note, you might have to reload your solution after making the above changes.